# ASP.NET MVC 4, Code First - Quickest way to purge test data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, entity-framework-migrations

My ASP.NET MVC 4 Code First app creates seed data using Migrations - works well.

Over time other test data I enter myself builds up.

What is the quickest way to delete this test data and return to just the seed data?

I do not want the database recreated every time I run my app.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way is to delete all data in your database and call the Seed function on your DbContextInitializer.

Deleting all your data in SQL Server is as simple as

```
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
GO
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO
```

At a higher leverl there are different database initializers available.

Out of the box you the following available.

- CreateDatabaseIfNotExists
- DropCreateDatabaseWhenModelChanges
- DropCreateDatabaseAlways

Switch out initializers depending on what you want to do.  Often I will do that in the global.asax file.